# Trying to stream H264 with Janus Gateway to web browser

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, h.264, janus

I have installed Janus-Gateway using the very comprehensive install instructions on an Ubuntu 18.04LTS machine.
I have configured the streaming config file (janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg) with:

```
gstreamer-sample: {
  type = "rtp"
  id = 1
  description = "H.264 live stream coming from gstreamer"
  audio = false
  video = true
  videoport = 5004
  videopt = 96
  videortpmap = "H264/90000"
  videofmtp = "profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1"
}
```

(I didn't change the name because that required least changes to other files.)

Having then started the server, I then take a pre-encoded stream and send that to the server with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:9034 -c:v copy -an -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:5004?pkt_size=1300
```

Opening up the demo webpage the server comes with, I go to streaming demos, and choose the "gstreamer" demo and click start.  The right hand half of the screen produces a spinning circle, but tells me that it is receiving data at the appropriate rate for the stream I'm sending.  So if it's receiving the stream, why isn't it playing it?

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: I ought to mention that I don't want to re-encode the stream from the point of view of CPU power and picture quality.

Comment: share the error logs and wireshark traces

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using GStreamer? I use this pipeline and it works for me.

gst-launch-1.0 -v file:///opt/janus3/share/janus/streams/beat.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay mtu=1300 config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.229 port=5004

Of couse, this example is streaming a local mp4 file instead of from an IP, but if this works for you then you can easily adjust it to work the way you want it to.